# Let $X,Y$ be independent, symmetrical, identically distributed, then $P( \mid X+Y\mid \leq 2 \mid X \mid )>1/2$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X,Y$ independent random variables, identically distributed and symmetric about $0$. Prove that:

$P( \mid X+Y\mid \leq 2 \mid X \mid )>1/2$

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1=P(|X+Y| \leq 2\max \{|X|,|Y|\}) \leq P(|X+Y| \leq 2|X|)+P(|X+Y| \leq 2|Y|)=2P(|X+Y| \leq 2|X|)$

Thus $P(|X+Y| \leq 2|X|) \geq \frac 1 2$. [ I have used the fact that $(X,Y)$ has same distribution as $(Y,X)$ so $P(|X+Y| \leq 2|X|)=P(|X+Y| \leq 2|Y|)$].

Comment: Thank you. It was very clear.

Answer (score 1):

$P(\lvert X+ Y \rvert < 2 \lvert X \rvert ) = P(\lvert X+ Y \rvert - 2 \lvert X \rvert < 0) > P(\lvert X \rvert + \lvert Y \rvert - 2 \lvert X \rvert ) = P(\lvert Y \rvert - \lvert X \rvert < 0) = P(\lvert Y \rvert < \lvert X \rvert ) = 1/2$$

If they are symmetric, than we can just as well consider iid variables on non-negative support. Then last equality is simple conclusion.